# Is it possible to set my Microphone device as my playback device?

Tags: windows-7, windows, microphone

I have some software that requires a microphone device in order to display sound visualizations.

Rather than use a microphone, I'd like to set my "microphone device" as my current playback device, so that whatever is played on my computer is sent to the microphone channel, without physically playing it through my speakers and picking it up with a physical microphone.

Is this possible in Windows?

Comment: What is the name of the software you are using?

Comment: @Sim, This needs to be a program independent solution.  I want to physically set my microphone device in ~windows~ to that of a playback device.  The software is some custom written visualization software used at the university.

Answer (score 2):

Try physically connecting your speaker output to your line-in or microphone.

Comment: +1 a 3.5mm stereo male-male "loopback" cable will do this without any background noise issues. Just need to control output volume levels and microphone recording levels to get that perfect sound

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Stereo Mix Device to record any internal spund of your pc, just enable it on your sound properties, Record tab. If the Stereo mix is not displayed you should Install the [Realtek High definition Audio Codecs](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false). After you have this device you can use any record program to rec the audio, should be Camtasia, SoundRec Pro or any other

[Sound properties Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkNV1.jpg)